# What are the educational requirement's for a US H1B Visa

Tags: usa, h1-visa

As I understand it, you need a 4 years of bachelor's degree, which means a total of 16 years of education for applying for an H1B visa. I have a bachelor's degree but for 2 years and 10 years of work experince in my field. So can I apply for the visa?

Does the combination of my 14 year's study and my 10 years of working experience qualify me to be eligible for an H1B visa?

Comment: I think [this duplicates the older question here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5506/what-is-the-minimum-level-of-experience-required-to-gain-a-us-h1b-visa). The answer is that it might, but it depends on you being able to document that the experience is equivalent to the missing 2 post-secondary years and that's a tough route to travel